# Problems getting object names

Tags: python, game-engine, blender

I have a blender scene with a few objects, I would get the object name when mouse is over one of them, setting a property of an empy object.
What I have now is just the list of the scene objects. What can I do?

```
import GameLogic
cont=GameLogic.getCurrentController()
obj=cont.getOwner()
print obj
objlist=GameLogic.getCurrentScene().getObjectList()
print objlist
sen=cont.getSensor('sensor')
if sen.isPositive():
    print objlist[0]
    PropName=.... #how to set this with the object name?
    print PropName
```

Comment: Are we to assume from the blender tag that this is working with 3D?  Are you using a specific framework for the window?  (Please excuse my lack of knowledge about blender's capabilities if this is answered already).

Comment: For 3D, a typical way to do this is to translate the mouse position on the window coordinate system into an angle from the camera position (depends on how your perspective matrix is defined), and then project the ray onto the scene.  The first object it intersects with is the selected object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be useful to someone else, I answer my own question. What I've done was to set a `mouse over` sensor to each objects within the scene and that add a python script controller, in order to set a property of the scene `Empty object`.

```
import GameLogic
import Rasterizer as r
r.showMouse(1)   #just in order to get the mouse visible within the game engine
print 'SetProperty.py\n'
cont=GameLogic.getCurrentController()
obj=cont.getOwner()
emptyOb = GameLogic.getCurrentScene().getObjectList()["OBEmpty"]
emptyOb.EmptyProp=obj
print 'object name, within emptyProp: ', emptyOb.EmptyProp
```

Comment: Just for sake of actuality (Blender 2.6&2.7 series): "Gamelogic" is replaced with "bge.logic"; I am not sure about "EmptyProp=obj" i guess it is just "emptyOb['somename'] = obj" but i am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use `SCA_MouseSensor` sensor and its `hitObject` property to get the last object the mouse was over. It returns `None` or an object of `KX_GameObject` type. When you get it, you can use its `name` property to get the name (or just access other properties of the object).

Reference links:

- [SCA_MouseSensor in API documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_0/bge.types.html#bge.types.SCA_MouseSensor)
- [KX_GameObject in API documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_0/bge.types.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject)

I haven't tested this yet, but I suppose it should work when used in Blender Game Engine. The information I've found refers to Blender 2.59, so make sure use are using appropriate version of the application.